# Python3 SimpleHTTPServer error

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, simplehttpserver

I am using SimpleHTTPServer in Python 3.4.3

```
python -m http.server
```

When I try to do a request from my client scrypt

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = path_leaf(url)

    try:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=6)
        r.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        print("HTTP exception error: {}".format(err))
        return
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Exception error: {}".format(e))
        return

    f = open(local_filename, 'wb')
    # File size in MB
    file_size = (int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0)) / (1024*1024))
    # This is a tenth of a file size for drawing a hash sign after every 10% is copied
    tenth_size = file_size / 10
    print("Downloading: {}, Size: {:.2f}MB ".format(url, file_size), end="", flush=True)
    copied = 0
    bar = 1
    start = time.time()
    # chunk is 1MB --> 1024x1kB
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024*1024):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
            copied += len(chunk) / (1024*1024)
            # Every 10% is copied, draw one hash sign
            if copied >= bar * tenth_size:
                print("#", end="", flush=True)
                bar += 1
    f.close()
    end = time.time()
    duration = end - start
    print(" 100% | {:.2f}s | {:.2f}MB/s, done.".format(duration, file_size/duration))
    return
```

it raises an timeout exception. This is the error which I get in my server console:

```
> Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
> 192.168.0.115 - - [21/Feb/2018 10:45:51] "GET /7z1604-x64(1).exe HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> ---------------------------------------- Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.0.115', 52472) Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 305,
> in _handle_request_noblock
>     self.process_request(request, client_address)   File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 331, in process_request
>     self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
>     self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "C:\Python34\lib\socketserver.py", line 673, in __init__
>     self.handle()   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 398, in handle
>     self.handle_one_request()   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 386, in handle_one_request
>     method()   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 680, in do_GET
>     self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)   File "C:\Python34\lib\http\server.py", line 839, in copyfile
>     shutil.copyfileobj(source, outputfile)   File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 70, in copyfileobj
>     fdst.write(buf)   File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 394, in write
>     return self._sock.send(b) ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
> ----------------------------------------
```

This doesn't happen every time, only, I think when server is idle some time. Then I have to press enter in http.server console to read the error. Right after, the request is working fine. Is it my code or is it bug in http.server?

Comment: Have you tried increasing timeout in `requests.get(url, stream=True, timeout=6)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have, to 27 and 54s. No change. And then I press enter at server console. The error output shows and after that request works. However, it will not be easy everytime to have access to server console :)

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't remember anymore how I solved this ... or did I solve it

Comment: Are you running it on windows powershell (cmd) or linux terminal?

Comment: Running it in windows cmd